# Azure Cognitive Search - Unable to create Datasource for Azure SQL Indexer from within the Azure Portal

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azureportal

Looking for some help with my sanity please.

I have created an Azure Search Services instance (Cognitive Search) but when I attempt to create an Datasource for an Azure SQL Indexer I receive errors in the portal.

[image: Error]

I have also tried to create the data source using the Azure SDK and whilst it "succeeds" it appears to be unusable for creating an Indexer (receive a 500 error).

I did this last week in another subscription and had no issues. I'm guessing this could be an intermittent Azure issue or I may have missed something simple. Any help to resolve this is greatly appreciated!

FYI. I've raised an Azure Feedback item here but I'm hoping someone has a workaround in the meantime:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/43745931-bug-the-portal-currently-shows-an-error-when-tryi

Comment: If you want, you can use [`Cerebrata Cerulean`](https://www.cerebrata.com/products/cerulean/features/azure-search/data-sources) as a stopgap arrangement to work with Cognitive Search. It's a commercial 3rd party tool (read: not free). Disclosure - I am part of the team behind this product.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this. A bug fix for this has been deployed, so it shouldn't be an issue any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it looks like there is an issue with the portal, but you can use the REST API to create it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-data-source

I just tested it, and it worked for me, had no issue while creating the index/indexer from that data source.

See example request below.

```
POST https://YOURSERVICENAME.search.windows.net/datasources?api-version=2020-06-30

{   
    "name" : "asqldatasource2",  
    "description" : "a description",  
    "type" : "azuresql",  
    "credentials" : { "connectionString" : "Server=tcp:yourserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=azdevtest;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;" },  
    "container" : { "name" : "Categories" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed a bug in the Portal. A fix has been deployed as of July 7, 2021.